# How to detect a URL which has additional text at the end?

Tags: php

I am currently designing a website which uses this: `<li class="current">`.

I have gotten a script to detect when it's on said page to output the right class, however, when on the gallery.php?dir=thedir page, it fails to output the class!

Here's what I have so far, which is not working...

```
$ispage = preg_match_all('gallery.php/\[(.+?)\]/s');
```

I would appreciate any information somebody could give me :).

Full code:

```
<?php 
$ispage = preg_match_all('gallery.php/\[(.+?)\]/s'); 
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
if ($ispage==$currentpage) { 
    echo '<li class="current">'; 
} else { 
    echo '<li>'; 
} 
?><a href="gallery.php">Photos</a></li>
```

Comment: Have you tried simple $_GET['dir'] ??

Comment: I have not... Though I fail to see how that would solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] or $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] along with php function strpos($haystack, $findme)? It should make your life easy.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Is there any chance you could provide an example? Thank you :)

Comment: Worked perfectly after a little fiddling, awesome answer, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you are trying to access query string values

Try  `echo $_GET['dir'];`

EDIT
Tried this?

```
$ispage = '/'.basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).'?'.($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$curepage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

I think you need to define an array of links to solve your problem

so that

```
$curpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$links = array('/gallery.php?dir=thedir', '/home.php?dir=anotherdir');

foreach($links as $link) {
   $class = '';

   if($link == $curpage) {
     $class = 'class="current"';

     echo '<li '.$class.'>';
     .... rest of the code .... 
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I need, I have updated the post to include the complete script, hopefully it explains a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is the one you need, it return the relative filename, without params.
Have a look here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure preg_match_all returns an int. If this is full code it won't be working at all. And yes, use something like `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`. Also you should think about using some better url to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php

$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];; 
preg_match('/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/', $currentpage, $matches);
if ($matches[0] == "/gallery.php?dir=thedir") { 
    echo '<li class="current">'; 
} else { 
    echo '<li>'; 
} 
?><a href="gallery.php">Photos</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

if a URL is something like:    *www.site.com/page.php?q=foo*

then this

```
$currentpage = basename(__FILE__);
```

will just give you **page.php**

In addition, if you call it this way:

```
$currentpage = basename(__FILE__,".php");
```

will give you **page**